# Haskell error when trying to get the last element

Tags: list, haskell, syntax-error

So, I am trying to implement a function that, given a list of 3 elements `((Int,Int),Int)`, returns `True` when on the second position is the same value for all 3 and `False` otherwise.

For instance, `[((1,2),7),((5,3),7),((1,9),7)]` should return `True` and `[((1,2),3),((5,3),3),((1,9),5)]` should return `False`.

Here is my code:

```
bc :: [((Int,Int),Int)]
wcheck :: [((Int,Int),Int)] -> Bool
wcheck bc
   | (( fst(fst bc) == fst(snd bc) ) && ( fst(snd bc) == fst(last bc) )) = True
   | otherwise                                                           = False
```

And the error that I get:

```
E:\\study related\Module1\week 4\ttt.hs:55:65: error:
* Couldn't match expected type `[(a, b0)]'
              with actual type `((a, b), (a, b1))'
* In the first argument of `last', namely `bc'
  In the first argument of `fst', namely `(last bc)'
  In the second argument of `(==)', namely `fst (last bc)'
* Relevant bindings include
    bc :: ((a, b), (a, b1))
      (bound at E:\\study related\Module1\week 4\ttt.hs:54:8)
    wcheck :: ((a, b), (a, b1)) -> Bool
      (bound at E:\\study related\Module1\week 4\ttt.hs:54:1)
   |
55 |  | (( fst(fst bc) == fst(snd bc) ) && ( fst(snd bc) == fst(last bc) )) = True
   |
```

Could you please tell me why I get this error and a way to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: So the list will always contain *three* elements? Wouldn't in that case a *tuple* make more sense, since then, the typesystem will *guarantee* that you nver enter something with less or more elements.

Comment: the type is already given to me and i have to build the function on it.

Comment: `wcheck :: Int -> [((Int,Int),Int)] -> Bool` is a function with two arguments, an int and a list. Where's the int argument in your code? What's its purpose?

Comment: my mistake. I edited the type to the correct form.

Comment: Well if `bc` is a list then `fst bc`, and `snd bc` does not make sense, since `fst` works over a 2-tuple, not a list (regardless whether these contain 2-tuples).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will probably be easier if we perform simple **pattern matching** instead of using `fst :: (a, b) -> a`, etc.

## Second item of the first item of the tuple

We can use a pattern `((_, x), _)` to obtain the second element from such 2-tuple wrapped in a 2-tuple.

So we can use pattern matching like:

```
wcheck :: [((Int,Int),Int)] -> Bool
wcheck [((_, x), _), ((_, y), _), ((_, z), _)] = x == y && y == z
wcheck _ = False
```

So here if the list contains three elements, we unpack the elements, and then check if the "second item"s are equal to each other. In case the pattern does not match (for a list with too few, or too much elements), we just return `False`.

But a "list of three elements" does not make much sense. In case the number of elements is known at compile time, it is better to use a tuple, since in that way, the compiler can verify that you can only provide 3-tuples to that function.

## Second item of the tuple

In case we are interested in the *second* item of the tuple, we can use `(_, x)` as pattern (we are not interested in the first item whatsoever):

```
wcheck :: [((Int,Int),Int)] -> Bool
wcheck [(_, x), (_, y), (_, z)] = x == y && y == z
wcheck _ = False
```

Note that we can generalize the signature with:

```
wcheck :: Eq c => [((a, b), c)] -> Bool
wcheck [(_, x), (_, y), (_, z)] = x == y && y == z
wcheck _ = False
```

Comment: Thank you. Though the pattern is ( ( _ , _ ) , x ), it works. Don't know why it didn't came to me. Maybe I was just too focused on using list comprehension.

Comment: @AndreiBercea: but in your qustion you say "second" value of the tuple, or do you mean the outer tuple.

Comment: I use the function to check if a row in a 3x3 matrix is filled with the same element ( I have to build a Tic-Tac-Toe game ).

Answer (score 2):

`fst` and `snd` are not very nice in this situation. We can extract the bit we care about by doing a pattern match:

```
let (_,y) = x in ...
```

Now you want to do that to each element of your list (to check that every element has the same second value):

```
map (\(_,x) -> x)
```

And then you want to check that they are all equal:

```
allEqual :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
allEqual [] = True
allEqual (x:xs) = all (\y->x==y) xs
```

This gets the first element, `x`, from a list (if it exists) and checks that ever other item `y` satisfies the test that `x==y`

So we can now write your function:

```
wcheck xs = allEqual (map (\(_,y) -> y) xs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want to test the equality of the second element of the outer pair, there are so many ways to do this, including the following.

First, fmapping `snd` gives you these elements:

```
λ> fmap snd [((1,2),7),((5,3),7),((1,9),7)]
[7,7,7]
```

Now you can group them to lists of consecutive equal numbers:

```
λ> import Data.List
λ> (group . fmap snd) [((1,2),7),((5,3),7),((1,9),7)]
[[7,7,7]]
```

The values are equal if the length of this list of lists is at most one (assuming an empty list of such pairs is defined to have equal second elements):

```
λ> (length . group . fmap snd) [((1,2),7),((5,3),7),((1,9),7)]
1
```

Putting these together we can define

```
import Data.List

equalSnds :: Eq a => [(b, a)] -> Bool
equalSnds xs = (length . group . fmap snd) xs <= 1
```

So that

```
λ> equalSnds [((1,2),7),((5,3),7),((1,9),7)]
True
λ> equalSnds [((1,2),3),((5,3),3),((1,9),5)]
False
```

If you want to also test for the length of the list, you can do it separately:

```
wcheck :: [((Int,Int),Int)] -> Bool
wcheck xs = length xs == 3 && equalSnds xs
```